# async/await function error in Babeljs version 6.16.0

Tags: async-await, babeljs

I'm normally using async/await and `syntax-async-functions`. But today when I upgraded to version 6.16.0, then my function async/await got error like below. I dont use  `for-of-await`. Now dont know how to config label to write async/await normally?
Tks.

```
Error: /usr/src/server.js: You gave us a visitor for the node type "ForAwaitStatement" but it's not a valid type
```

Comment: You didn't include your error message (or any code that could be used to reproduce the issue). Before anyone can help, you'll need to paste it in to the post.